# What's the difference static or inline in C++

Tags: c++, static

I'm new to C++, I'm confused about `static` and `inline`. What I want to do is defining a global counter. I test it on the code as below (*it is just a skeleton to illustrate the idea*)

```
// in main.cc
#include "T.h"

int main() {
  runFuncInT() ;
  cout << "# of trans is " << trans_cnt ;
  return 0;
}

// in T.h
static size_t trans_cnt = 0;

// in T.cc
runFuncInT() {
  for (size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
    trans_cnt += 1;
}
```

If I use the descriptive `inline`, everything is perfect and output is `# of trans is 10`. However, if I use `static`, the compiler throws an error `multiple definition of trans_cnt`.

Comment: There should not be a multiple definition error if you use `static`. Please check the code you posted is exactly what you are compiling (and that you recompiled the whole project when making the change)

Comment: @M.M thanks for your answer. The project is too complex so that I might make some wrongs here. But the thing is `inline` indeed does not trigger any error but `static` throws this kind of error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++17 you should declare your variable in the header as `inline`:

```
inline size_t trans_cnt = 0;
```

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline:

> since C++17: Because the meaning of the keyword `inline` for functions came to mean "multiple definitions are permitted" rather than "inlining is preferred", that meaning was extended to variables.

---

Prior to C++17, if you declare a variable in a header file that is included in multiple translation units you need to declare that variable in the header as `extern` and define in one of the `.cc`. E.g.:

```
// in T.h
extern size_t trans_cnt;

// in T.cc
size_t trans_cnt = 0; // T.h must have been included.
```

---

Yet, alternatively, you can use a function static variable of a function defined as `inline` in a header as a singleton, e.g.:

```
// in T.h
inline size_t& trans_cnt() {
    static size_t value = 0;
    return value;
}
```

For classes with a non-constexpr constructor that `static` function local variable is initialized with `std::call_once`, which isn't expensive but not free (and, for this reason, I don't use this method myself).

---

And another method to avoid defining that variable elsewhere is static data member of a template, which must be both defined and declared in the header:

```
// in T.h
template<class T, class Tag = void> struct Static { static T value; }; // Declaration.
template<class T, class Tag> T Static<T, Tag>::value{}; // Definition and initialization with empty initializer-list.
// refer to it as Static<size_t>::value; 
// E.g.:
int main() {
    size_t& trans_cnt = Static<size_t>::value;
    size_t& trans_cnt2 = Static<size_t, struct the_second_one>::value;
    size_t& trans_cnt3 = Static<size_t, struct the_third_one>::value;
}
```

---

In comparison, C++17 `inline` variable and `static` function locals with `constexpr` constructor (includes all built-in types) use exactly the same mechanism as static data member of a class template: each translation unit includes a copy of the variable, but the linker and run-time linker pick one for all translation units to use via [vague linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vague-Linkage.html).

The declaration with `extern` and definition in one translation unit of the entire program is ideal because the variable is defined truly once and no further linker effort is required.

Comment: Great! Thanks, got it

Comment: @stickers If this answer addressed your question, consider accepting it.